# Struggling with badge pull-right in horizontal tab (IE9 only)

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I have a fiddle that words in IE8, Chrome and Firefox but fails in IE9.

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 and I want the badges to be on the same line as the text but on the right.  This works in every browser but IE9.  In IE9 the badge shows up below the text.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DvxHe/

```
<div class='tabs-left'>
  <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li>
      <a href="#specializations_tab" data-toggle="tab">
        Specializations
        <span id="specializations-count" class="badge badge-info section-count pull-right">
          0
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!-- lots more like above -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: does white-space:nowrap on the li > a fix it?

Comment: Nm, it won't because of the float. Wrap the text in a span as well and add the clearfix to the a href. If you have enough room to expand they shouldn't wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the width of the nav-tabs either by user bootstrap colums layout or by setting a fixed width. As a test, by simply adding style="width:180px" to the nav-tabs, everything is fine.

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvxHe/2/) that has the following CSS:

```
.nav-tabs {
    width:180px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  It's sad that I have to set an explicit width for this one browser though.

Comment: You can also use percentage if you prefer. Or better let bootstrap do all this for you by using its column layout system. :)

Comment: As for bootstrap's layout system I have all of this wrapped in a row-fluid so it should work... it just doesn't on ie9

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in IE by simply removing the pull-right class.

Bootstrap has the badges styled for nav-tabs. The pull-right class is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the span element just remove the pull-right class and shift the header text to the left of the span tag. In The css,for badge class make white-space as important. Make the display of `ul` as a table and put the table-layout fixed.

In the list element use the style `display:table-cell`

Try the following example:

```
/*In Css*/
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

And in your HTML

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%; display: table;table-layout: fixed;">

    <li class="active" style="display: table-cell">
        <a href="#Inbound" data-toggle="tab" `enter code here`style="text-decoration: none">Messages<span class="badge" runat="server" id="MsgCount">0</span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```